# Detach child, update, and attach? AndEngine, Android

Tags: android, andengine

```
engine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.2f,
            new ITimerCallback() {
                public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                    pTimerHandler.reset();
                    Rectangle xpRect = new Rectangle(30, 200,
                            (float) (((player.getXp()) / (player
                                    .getNextLevelxp())) * 800), 40, vbom);
                    HUD.attachChild(xpRect);
                }
            }));
```

I have this so far in my createHUD method. It's pretty simple, it creates a rectangle showing the player's xp in relation to the xp needed for the next level and attaches it to the HUD. The only problem is that the old rectangle is never deleted. How can I have a rectangle like that one that updates itself and removes old ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the detachChild() or any other detach method too regularly, you might run into problems sooner or later. Especially because the *detaching* can only be made on an `update thread`. You'll never know when exactly your rectangle will be detached again. So, to save you a lot of attaching and detaching, reuse the rectangle:

**i) Save a reference of the Rectangle somewhere (as a global variable for example in your `Player`class).**

**ii) At the beginning when you load your stuff also initialize the rectangle:**

```
 Rectangle xpRect = new Rectangle(30, 200, 0, 40, vbom);   // initialize it
 HUD.attachChild(xpRect);      // attach it where it belongs
 xpRect.setVisible(false);     // hide it from the player
 xpRect.setIgnoreUpdate(true); // hide it from the update thread, because you don't use it.
```

At this point it doesn't matter where you put your rectangle or how big it is. It's only important that it is there.

**iii) Now when you want to show the player his XP you only have to make it visible**

```
 public void showXP(int playerXP, int nextXP){
     float width= (float) ((playerXP / nextXP) * 800);  // calculate your new width
     xpRect.setIgnoreUpdate(false);     // make the update thread aware of your rectangle
     xpRect.setWidth(width);            // now change the width of your rectangle
     xpRect.setVisible(true);           // make the rectangle visible again              
 }
```

**iv) When you no longer need it: In order to make it invisible again just call**

```
  xpRect.setVisible(false);     // hide it from the player
  xpRect.setIgnoreUpdate(true); // hide it from the update thread, because you don't
```

Of course you can now use the `showXP()` method in anyway you like and use it in your `TimerHandler`. If you want a more effect full appearance you do something like this instead:

```
 public void showXP(int playerXP, int nextXP){
     float width= (float) ((playerXP / nextXP) * 800);  // calculate your new width
     xpRect.setIgnoreUpdate(false);                     // make the update thread aware of your rectangle
     xpRect.setWidth(width);                            // now change the width of your rectangle
     xpRect.setVisible(true); 

     xpRect.registerEntityModifier(new FadeInModifier(1f));  // only this line is new
 }
```

It's actually the same as the above method with just a little change in the last line, that makes the rectangle appear a little more smoothly...

Answer (score 0):

To detach a child from a HUD ,you can write

```
    aHUD.detachChild(rectangle);
```

To clear all children from HUD

```
aHUD.detachChildren();
```

To to clear all HUD from camera , you can write

```
 cCamera.getHUD().setCamera(null);
```

After using one of above, You can create a HUD & also attach as usual.